# RhoConnect - uninitialized constant when calling Rho methods

Tags: ruby, twitter, rhomobile

I'm attempting to make a RhoMobile application that will display a Twitter feed using RhoConnect. In my RhoConnect app, in the source adapter's model, I've attempted to use the methods **Rho::AsyncHttp** and **Rho::Network** in order to perform the POST request to Twitter e.g.

```
Rho::Network.post(propertyMap, url_for(:action => :request_callback))
```

However, when attempting to sync the RhoMobile app (running in RhoSimulator) with the RhoConnect app I get the error:

```
Model raised login exception: uninitialized constant Twitter::Rho
```

And it points to the line in my code above.

This may well be a really obvious mistake, but I can't see it. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rho::AsyncHttp** and **Rho::Network** are Rhodes APIs. You use these APIs in the application on the device, not inside a RhoConnect source adapter.

In a source adapter, that is running on a linux machine on top of the Ruby environment, you can use whatever gem you want to talk to different backend systems. You can find more information about this on the [RhoMobile documentation site](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoconnect/source-adapters).

In your case, having to connect to Twitter, you can use in your source adapter something like the [Twitter gem](http://sferik.github.io/twitter/).

Comment: Ah, how silly of me. I'm still getting used to all the components of RhoMobile. At the moment I'm using RestClient to interact with the Twitter API, but I'll look at that gem, thanks.